# How to compare 2 list and prioritize the order in python

Tags: python

I have 2 lists as below.

```
L1 = ['Apple', 'Watermelon', 'Orange' ,'Grapes']
# L1 is the actual priority list

L2 = ['Apple','Apple_1', 'Watermelon', 'Orange' ,'Grapes', 'Watermelon_1', 'Watermelon_2']
# L2 is newly created list
```

//*_1, *_2, *_3 this will be not be restricted, it may increase/ decrease depending on search found

**Expected List:**
// The new list has to be created by comparing the priority order of L1 list

```
L_out = ['Apple_1', 'Apple', 'Watermelon_2', 'Watermelon_1', 'Watermelon', 'Orange', 'Grapes']
```

Comment: it is not a list in python. do you mean set?

Comment: sorry had written { instead of [

Comment: super ugly `sorted(L2, key = lambda x: (L1.index(x.split('_')[0]), -int(0 if len(x.split('_'))==1 else x.split('_')[1])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a custom sorter that can:

- Criterion 1: Use **index** of element from your priority list.
- Criterion 2: Adjust the offset with your suffix (solves conflict): **Apple, Apple_1**

```
x = ['Apple', 'Apple_1', 'Watermelon', 'Orange', 'Grapes', 'Watermelon_1', 'Watermelon_2']
r = ['Apple', 'Watermelon', 'Orange', 'Grapes']

def sort_entries(entry):
    values = entry.split("_")
    suffix = values[-1] if len(values) > 1 else 0
    return r.index(values[0]) if values[0] in r else -1, -int(suffix)


print(sorted(x, key=sort_entries))
```

Output:

```
['Apple_1', 'Apple', 'Watermelon_2', 'Watermelon_1', 'Watermelon', 'Orange', 'Grapes']
```

Comment: use two sort criteria `return r.index(values[0]), -int(suffix)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands thanks that's helpful. can sort criteria be chained to any level?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Well yes, the key function can theoretically return a tuple of any length

Comment: Getting this error ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list

Comment: that's when the element is not present in priority list. i've updated my answer to prevent error, but how do you want it work for elements not in priority list?